# Screen auto-rotation not working in Ubuntu 20.10 with GNOME 3.38.1

Tags: gnome, display

I have a 2-in-1 laptop that I sometimes use in tablet mode. However when I physically rotate the device, the display orientation stays them same. How can I get it to auto-rotate?
EDIT: An update fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same issue with Lenovo laptop.
Since 20.10 default video server is Wayland, instead of good old XORG. Auto-rotation (or any rotation) is not working properly under Wayland. If you switch back your session to XORG, everything will work fine. It didn't work properly in 20.04LTS under Wayland as well. Canonical must fix that if they pushing Wayland as a default.